# Merge two JSON data into one with particular key values

Tags: json, reactjs

I have two CSV files:

balldata.json

```js
    [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "color": "red",

      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "color": "blue",
      }]
```

court.json:

```js
    [
      {
        "court_id": 2001,
        "ball_in_use": "1",
      },
      {
        "court_id": 2005,
        "ball_in_use": "2",
      }]
```

How can I map the color of the ball based on the court id? For example: 
2001 --> red, 2005 --> blue

I tried below approach

```js
    const App = (props) =>{
        let color = balldata.map((c, index) => {
          return c.id + "-" + c.color;})
        let game = courtdata.map((ball, index) => {
          return ball.ball_in_use;})
        return(
          //not sure what to return here since I am unable to use {color} or {game}
    )}
```

Comment: Can you define the desired output?

Comment: 2001 --> red, 2005 --> blue, where 2001 is the court id

Comment: I've posted a solution, you can use any approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below

```js
const result = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, {color: q[i].color})));

// Result

[ 
 {court_id: 2001, ball_in_use: "1", color: "red"},
 {court_id: 2005, ball_in_use: "2", color: "blue"}
]
```

> else use below

```js
const result = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, {[c.court_id] : q[i].color})))

//Result

[
 {2001: "red"}, 
 {2005: "blue"}
]
```

Working example **https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-b7bfm**

Comment: i tried both and it says `TypeError: p.map is not a function`

Comment: oh, i found out what was wrong. how do I console.log by the way?

Comment: I update the answer. Storing final data in `result`. So you can `console.log(result)` directly. and use same in your app. 

Comment: it works! now how can I call it in the return part of my code? {result} did not work

Comment: What you want to render via App?

Comment: I want to render the mappings from one json to another

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216042/discussion-between-harish-sharma-and-jason1234).

Comment: sorry, i was away.

Comment: hi, can you please take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419827/map-data-using-useref-hook