# Map data using useRef Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am following this: [Merge two JSON data into one with particular key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403409/merge-two-json-data-into-one-with-particular-key-values)

Now, I added an `useEffect()` hook. How can I make use of useRef to store my result? This is an asynchronous function.

```
const App = (props) =>{
    let result = useRef ()
    useEffect(()=>{
      return()=>
        (result.current = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, 
        {[c.court_id] : q[i].color}))))
      }.[someTrigger])
   return(
        <ul>
           {result.current.map(r => (
           <li>
             Court id - {r.court_id} | Ball colour - {r.color}
           </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
)
}
```

Now my {r.court_id} and {r.color} are empty.

Things I have tried:

```
const App = (props) =>{
       [result, setResult] = useState({})
        useEffect(()=>{
          setResult([courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, 
            {[c.court_id] : q[i].color}))))
          }))
       return(
            <ul>
               {result.map(r => (
               <li>
                 Court id - {r.court_id} | Ball colour - {r.color}
               </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
)
}
```

error:
`TypeError: result.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your render statement, resolve data like below

> If you choose `useState` option

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const final = [courtdata, balldata].reduce((p, q) => p.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, {color: q[i].color})));
    setResult(final);
  }, []);
```

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-shz9v

Comment: why is it that when i removed `useEffect`, i will have an error that states `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`?

Comment: hey, there is an issue here. the the `const final` statement is always re-rendering and it's causing my application to hang

Comment: Updated Answer.. Now it will render once only

Comment: It will render only once just like `ComponentDidMount`

Comment: why does removing that works? i thought the property of `useEffect()` is if something changes, it will re-render. but why does it keep re-rendering even when there are no changes? And how do the application know when to re-render since it has been removed?

Comment: Effects are always executed after the render phase is completed even if you setState inside the one effect, another effect will read the updated state and take action on it only after the render phase. So we can stop calling `useEffect` again, by passing `[]` blank array or making it conditional e.g `if(!result.length) setResult(final)`

Comment: are you able to help me out with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507601/reactjs-doesnt-run-functions-inside-object-assign?noredirect=1#comment110546437_62507601

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` hook execute after component mounted, and `useRef` is to access some dom component.

I think what you need is `useState`.

```js
const [result, setResult] = useState({});
```

Comment: I have tried that and it seems that I have an error. I have edited my question

Comment: result.map suppose the result is an array, you need to do
`const [result, setResult] = useState([]);`, useEffect will execute later then the component mount

Comment: i do not have error anymore, but my output is still null. Probably because the result inside my `useEffect()` isn't captured

Comment: Try to use react devtool to see if the state has been updated.